# Upper_bound для pair

Tags: c++, синтаксис, binary, data-structures

Язык: С++

Имеется упорядоченный по возрастанию массив пар p с значениями заданными от p[1] до p[2*n]. Нужно при введенном x найти мин. индекс index такой, что x < p[index].first (значения в p.second не важно) или формально upper_bound. Пытался ввести следующие команды:

```
                  int index = upper_bound(p + 1, p + 2 * n + 1, x);
```

Или же через лямбда функции

```
 int index = upper_bound(p + 1, p + 2*n + 1, x, [&](pair u){
                        return (u.first < x);
});
```

В первый раз вожусь с этой функцией, и уверен что ошибка просто в моем незнании синтаксиса. Можете помочь с проблемой, плюс разъяснить по полкам синтаксис upper_bound (по крайней мере ссылку: можно и на английском)

Ремарка: понимаю что можно просто переписать p.first значения в одномерный массив и для него делать upper_bound с первой выше написанной командой, но просто самому хотелось бы разобраться в синтаксисе на будущее.

Comment: Минутку. `p` - пара? Массив пар? Если массив - упорядоченный? Как именно? Ведь `upper_bound` имеет свои требования...

Comment: pair<int,int> p[20005];

Comment: Упорядочены или нет? По первому полю? Это - требование `upper_bound` - что все элементы, меньшие искомого, должны быть слева, а большие - справа...  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound

Comment: аа ну да, массив упорядочен через sort(p+1,p+2*n+1),

Comment: Почему вы, кстати, все время работаете от `p+1` - первый элемент массива у вас не задействован?

Comment: Мне удобнее работать с p[1]...p[2*n] чем с p[0]...p[2*n-1]. Разве для этого p+1 не нужно? Или я чего-то не догоняю?

Comment: Просто непривычно. Выбрасывать один элемент просто чтоб везде за собой тягать `+1` - мало кто делает...

Comment: вам нужен минимальный индекс, т.е. первый элемент, удовлетворяющий условию. Так причем тут  upper_bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, нужно примерно так:

```
auto i = upper_bound(p,p+2*n,make_pair(x,0));
```

Или, если вам критично от `p[1]`, то

```
auto i = upper_bound(p+1,p+2*n+1,make_pair(x,0));
```

Просто вы же должны сравнивать *однотипные* величины...

Да, вернет функция никак *не индекс*, а итератор на найденный элемент (или итератор за конец массива). В cлучае массива это будет указатель

```
pait<int,int>*
```

P.S. Ан, нет - насчет типа соврал. Вы *можете* передавать и `int`, вот так:

```
auto i = upper_bound(p,p+2*n,value,[](int x, const pair<int,int>& z){ return x < z.first; });
```

Но это все немножко на грани фола - потому что если только ваша функция сравнения не будет соответствовать требованию `upper_bound`, то результат может быть самым неверным... Но в этом конкретном случае сравнение первого поля с переданным значением для отсортированного массива удовлетворяет условию.

Comment: аа, вы имеете ввиду, что upper_bound(....) это pointer, а я сравнил с int-ом?

Comment: Вы пытались сравнивать `pair` с `int`, в то время как функция требует `pair`...

Comment: int index = int(upper_bound(p+1,p+2*n+1,x) - p); --> так сойдет?

Comment: Ну, в принципе, да.